# Transforming Dataset into value matrix

Tags: r

Sorry about the hopeless title..

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
|userId|movieId|rating|genre1|genre2|
|1     |13     |3.5   |1     |0     |
|1     |412    |2.5   |1     |1     |
|2     |4      |3.0   |0     |1     |
|3     |412    |2.5   |1     |1     |
|4     |13     |4.5   |1     |0     |
|4     |412    |5     |1     |1     |
```

And so on...

Not every user has rated every movie.

I want to transform this into a matrix that looks like:

```
|   |1  |2  |3  |4  |
|4  |   |3  |   |   |
|13 |2.5|   |   |4.5|
|412|   |   |   |5  |
```

So I have userId as the columns and movieId as the rows with the associated value being the rating given.

What's the best way of doing this?

Edit: The id's are non-sequential. There are 140k users and 28k movies.

Comment: the best way is to attempt it first yourself so that you can learn from your mistakes and others can help you when you have shown effort `reshape(df[, 1:3], dir = 'wide', idvar = 'movieId', timevar = 'userId')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have several users and several movies, you could easily run out of memory in building a `matrix`. For instance say that users are 1000 and the different movies are 1000. You'll end up with a `matrix` containing 1M entries, most of them will be missing (since not every users saw every movie).

If your dataset is big, a `sparseMatrix` from the `Matrix` package is the way to go. If both users and movies id's are sequential (i.e. they start with 1 and finish with the number of different entries), building it is straightforward. Using @StevenBeaupré `data`:

```
require(Matrix)
mat<-sparseMatrix(df$userId,df$movieId,x=df$rating)
```

If the id's are not sequential:

```
mat<-sparseMatrix(as.integer(factor(df$userId)), 
                  as.integer(factor(df$movieId)),x=df$rating)
```

You can basically perform any `matrix` operation on a `sparseMatrix` too.

Comment: The id's are unfortunately not sequential. There is 140k users and 28k movies so yeah it will be pretty big almost 4billion entries

Comment: You cannot handle it with a standard matrix. See my edit to handle non sequential id's.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this out now. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(-(genre1:genre2)) %>%
  spread(userId, rating, fill = "")
```

Which gives:

```
#  movieId   1 2   3   4
#1       4     3        
#2      13 3.5       4.5
#3     412 2.5   2.5   5
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(userId = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), movieId = c(13L, 
412L, 4L, 412L, 13L, 412L), rating = c(3.5, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 4.5, 
5), genre1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), genre2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("userId", "movieId", "rating", "genre1", 
"genre2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I tried this method, due to the large size of my dataset (140k users, 28k movies) I ran out of storage space on my MBP, apparently something took up 100GB of space. I should have mentioned the dataset size in the OP.