# Huge dataframe to spread

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I have a huge df which dimension is (58556185 X 2)

```
user page  like
  1    A    1
  1    B    1
  1    C    1
  2    A    1
  2    C    1
  3    B    1
  .    .    .
```

and the unique user and unique pages are 100,000 and 50,000 respectively
I want to spread it into

```
user/page
   A   B   C ...
1  1   1   0 ...
2  1   0   1 ...
3  0   1   0 ...
.
.
```

I have used this code and it works for small dataset

```
data <- data%>%
  group_by(user)%>%
  spread(page, like, fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
```

But when apply to huge df, it comes out `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 21626.2 Gb`

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: There are lots of posts about how to handle this issue. [Did you google ?](https://www.google.co.in/search?site=&source=hp&q=cannot+allocate+vector+of+size+in+r&oq=cannot+allocate+vector+of+size+in+r).

Comment: Did you calculated how many rows `(length(unique(df$user)))` and how many columns `(length(unique(df$page)))` your spreaded matrix will have? I'm not sure if you really want that.

Comment: It's not a good idea. The resulting object would be huge. Consider instead using a `sparseMatrix`. See this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457501/transforming-dataset-into-value-matrix/33457722

Comment: final output will be a  100000 * 50000 dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used sparse matrix to solve this problem.

```
mat <- sparseMatrix(as.integer(factor(data.fbpage$uid)) ,as.integer(factor(data.fbpage$pageId)), x=data.fbpage$like)
```