# Transforming the latest MovieLens dataset (ratings) into a matrix including NAs

Tags: r

I'm trying to transform the latest MovieLens Dataset (small) into a matrix. Basically it's a 'list' with three columns: userID, movieID and ratings. I want the users to be the rows, the items to be the columns and the ratings should be the content of the matrix.

I already searched on stackoverflow before but the closest approach I found was this one: [Transforming Dataset into value matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457501/transforming-dataset-into-value-matrix)

Actually, this approach did work really really well but if I use the sparseMatrix-function I got no NAs in the matrix. Of course the sparseMatrix is a good way to save storage capacity but I need the NAs in the matrix since I use them to compute the number of similar items between two users etc.

The dataset looks like this:

```
|userId|movieId|rating
|1     |1      |3.5   
|1     |3      |2.5   
|1     |5      |3.0   
|1     |412    |2.5  
|2     |13     |4.5   
|3     |412    |5
```

and so on.

Now I want to transform this dataset into a matrix so that it looks like this:

```
   1   | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ... 
1| 3,5 |NA |2,5| NA|3,0| ... 
_____________________

2| NA |NA  |NA | NA| NA| ... 
_____________________

3| NA |NA  |NA | NA|5,0| ... 
______________________
```

I hope this visulization helped a little to understand my problem. I am so sorry if it does not look like a typical question on stackoverflow but I am very new here.

It would be awesome if one of you would have a solution for my problem! Many thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: Code, data, anything really... give us something to work with.

Comment: Hey cory, I edited my original question to make it more understandable. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Search for "long to wide". Basically use something like `spread(df, key=movieId, value=rating)` .